# How can i change the app settings language based on selected app language in ios.?

Tags: ios, localization

My app supports 7 language. when the user selects from the choice i will restart the app so that app changes to the selected language. But i need the app settings such as settings bundle to be updates as per the app language.I can able to localise the settings based on device language but not on selected app language.

Comment: Update / Re Write your setting bundle when changing language from app.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be a hard NO for it. Inter-App communication doesn't let you localize the native apps.

App is localized to spanish but device is set to english then

- If your app is showcasing address then book english is shown.
- If the app is using camera then english is shown (unlesss you create
  custom camera interface)
- If app is triggering social framework like Facebook,twitter etc they
  also shown in english.

Here in your case the Settings screen can be localized just in the same way that info plist localizes, but screen will localized only when the device is set to that language. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/localizing-iphone-app-settings-strings/